# How to detect if the bot has been mentioned?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How can I detect if my bot is mentioned?

I tried these thus far:

```
if (msg.content.toLowerCase().includes('@The Guardian of The Bar#5180')) {
  msg.channel.send("My prefix here is" + prefix + "\n You can start with ``" + prefix + "help``");
}
```

```
if (msg.content.toLowerCase().includes('@The Guardian of The Bar')) {
  msg.channel.send("My prefix here is" + prefix + "\n You can start with ``" + prefix + "help``");
}
```

```
if (msg.content.includes('@The Guardian of The Bar#5180')) {
  msg.channel.send("My prefix here is" + prefix + "\n You can start with ``" + prefix + "help``");
}
```

```
if (msg.content.includes('@The Guardian of The Bar#5180')) {
  msg.channel.send("My prefix here is" + prefix + "\n You can start with ``" + prefix + "help``");
}
```

Comment: Instead of share image add some of your related code.

Comment: @Md.SukelAli I did. Can you help me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not experienced in discord.js, but according to [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Message?scrollTo=isMemberMentioned) in the documentation, a message object has a method `message.isMemberMentioned(User or GuildMember)`. Using this method, one can use

```
client.on('message', message => { //this event is fired, whenever the bot sees a new message
   if (message.isMemberMentioned(client.user)) { //we check, whether the bot is mentioned, client.user returns the user that the client is logged in as
      //this is where you put what you want to do now
   }
});
```

I would like to recommend, that you read the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable) fully, before you try to make a bot.

On v12 discord.js you now have to use `message.mentions.has(bot.user)`