# My Discord bot recently won't respond when mentioned

Tags: triggers, botframework, discord, discord.js, mention

This is my first time using this site so I apologize if the formatting's sub par.

**The problem:**
My Discord bot (*javascript*) recently has stopped responding when @mentioned. There were no changes to the code to cause this and it was working perfectly fine not too long ago. A friend who's bot is programmed similarly also has this issue so I know that it's not only me.

The bot's basically a chat-and-reply bot; you @mention it's name and include a trigger and it has a random chance to respond with one of four responses. However, something's happened where it doesn't seem to register that it's been @mentioned and therefore doesn't reply.

*So, for example, if I were to type "@bot hi!" in discord, the bot would reply with one of the following replies: "It's too early for this.", "Mornin'.", "I need coffee.". "[yawn, mumbled greeting]".*

I've tried replacing `client.user.toString()` directly with it's client identifier as well as the identifiers that would be used in discord (for example; "@name#0000", "<@########>") but those are also ignored. I've added an arrow next to this area in the code.

I'm not sure if there was an update that's made some of the code go out of date, but I've tried searching for similar issues with no success.

I'm relatively sure that the issue isn't with the `processChat(receivedMessage)` function, as I can replace the noted problem section with an alternate trigger such as:

```
if (receivedMessage.content.startsWith("@all ")) {
        processChat(receivedMessage)
}
```

and the bot will send a reply. It simply doesn't seem to want to respond when mentioned; the rest of the code works as it should. While this is something I can convert to, I've had this bot on my server for almost a year now and there are multiple other server members who'd need to adapt to the change. I'd rather get things running the way they used to than have everyone fall out of habit to compensate.

Is there a way to fix this?

Here's a small example code that has the same issue:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
   console.log("Connected as " + client.user.tag);
})

//The color for all of the bot's messages
messageColor = 4611141;

client.on('message', receivedMessage => {
    // Prevent bot from responding to its own messages
    if (receivedMessage.author == client.user) {
        return;
    }    

    //process regular triggers (@ mentions)
    //This is where the issue seems to be           <--------------------------
    if ((receivedMessage.content.includes(client.user.toString()))) {
        processChat(receivedMessage);
    }    
});

//For usage with chat prompts and triggers
function processChat(receivedMessage) {

    if ((receivedMessage.content.toLowerCase().includes("hi"))){
      var random = randomInt(5, 1) ;
        if (random == 1) {
            receivedMessage.channel.send({embed: {
              color: messageColor,
              description: "It's too early for this."
            }});         
        } else if (random == 2) {
            receivedMessage.channel.send({embed: {
              color: messageColor,
              description: "Mornin'."
            }}); 
        } else if (random == 3) {
            receivedMessage.channel.send({embed: {
              color: messageColor,
              description: "I need coffee."
            }}); 
        } else if (random == 4) {
            receivedMessage.channel.send({embed: {
              color: messageColor,
              description: "*[yawn, mumbled greeting]*"
            }});    
        } else {
           return;
        }
    } 
}


//Random number generation
function randomInt(max, min) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

client.on('error', console.error);

client.login(token)
```

Comment: Did you give your bot a nickname? The [mention format changes](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting) in that case so `user.toString()` won't be correct. If you want to check for mentions properly there's plenty of [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55195128/how-to-detect-if-the-bot-has-been-mentioned/55195468#55195468) on SO that answer that.

Comment: The bot doesn't have a nickname. I figured that problem out a while ago and so I haven't messed with it. Thank you for that link, however. It answered my question nicely; I guess I didn't search with quite the right tags.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to add [SOLVED] to the question title or edit a solution into the question. If you've received an answer here that solved the problem, you can mark it as accepted to indicate that it did so. If you've found a solution yourself and want to share it, you can do so by writing an answer in the space below provided for that use (see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from

```
if ((receivedMessage.content.includes(client.user.toString()))) {
        processChat(receivedMessage);
    }
```

to

```
if (recievedMessage.isMemberMentioned(client.user)) {
        processChat(recievedMessage)
    }
```

Solved the problem. Thanks, Bauke, for those links.