# How do I make it so when a user tags the discord bot, it responds with a message?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a discord bot, in JavaScript and I was wondering how I could make it so when a user ran a message which only contained the bots mention, it would respond with a message such as `The server prefix is... <prefix>`.

I have tried adding this in the prefix file but nothing actually happened when I mentioned the bot.

```
if (message.content.startsWith("<@649042475557584896>") {
  return message.channel.send(`The server prefix is... ${args[0]}`)
}.
```

I even tried setting it in an embed, to make it cleaner but that didnt help either.

Comment: Probably what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55195128/how-to-detect-if-the-bot-has-been-mentioned

Comment: @omegatrix is right. But note that in Discord JS v12 it has been changed to [message.mentions.has()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=has)

Comment: @Jakye thanks for spotting that! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the propertie `isMemberMentioned()` from the Message object.

Little example:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.isMemberMentioned(client.user)){
      //do your code here...
    }
}
```

WARNING! It seems it's deprecated. V12 seems to don't work with it.
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Message?scrollTo=isMemberMentioned

Comment: ill give it a shot, im still on v11, so hopefully i shouldnt have any issues with it?.