# How to detect when bot is mentioned

Tags: discord.js

Before you mark this a duplicate, I have already tried this post: [How to detect if the bot has been mentioned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55195128/how-to-detect-if-the-bot-has-been-mentioned)

```
else if (message.mentions.has(client.user)) { 
    message.channel.send("https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/L-agoqC2Qsf2sdz4tdrcD5hUiJe6moglhwHjXPi8McE/https/i.imgflip.com/3ia3r2.png")
    console.log('Bot was mentioned')
 }
```

I have it to log when it is mentioned but doesn't log, so i figure that it doesn't detect it being mentioned. Is there a different way to detect if the bot is mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

The annoying thing with `if (message.mentions.has(...)` is that it would make the bot react even when @everyone or @here are mentioned, hence why I don't recommend using it.

The best thing yet, unfortunately, the ugliest thing to do, would be to have an if statement checking if the message includes a client mention, that can be done using:

```
if (message.content.includes(`<@!${client.user.id}>`) console.log('Bot was mentioned!')
```

Comment: Hmmm. Doesn't seem to work. I tried changing the {client.user.id} to the bot's id but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check for a mention to a specific `Guild#GuildMember`, you should write

```
if (message.mentions.members.has(<Client>.user.id)) {
    message.channel.send("https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/L-agoqC2Qsf2sdz4tdrcD5hUiJe6moglhwHjXPi8McE/https/i.imgflip.com/3ia3r2.png");
    console.log('Bot was mentioned');
}
```

This will check for the direct mention to the bot.

Comment: The (<Client>.user.id)) is supposed to be (client.user.id)) right? because when it has the "<>" it causes errors. Either way, still doesn't work for me. I suppose its a problem with my bot because it works for you

Comment: I wrote <client> To identify the client in general. So anybody can use this line. But yeah it is supposed to be client.user.id. Can you try to replace "has" with "includes"?

Comment: Still doesn't work. Definitely something wrong with my bot. Not getting any errors and no other commands are working now so i'll look into it